# How to pass json array from one activity to another and display it in a listview android

Tags: android, listview, arrays

JSON responce is

> {"DbList":[{"DataBaseName":"BRISBANE","UserID":"1","WebAdmin":true},{"DataBaseName":"CENTRES","UserID":"100001","WebAdmin":true},{"DataBaseName":"MEL","UserID":"1","WebAdmin":true},{"DataBaseName":"NSW","UserID":"10001","WebAdmin":true},{"DataBaseName":"OPERATORS","UserID":"1","WebAdmin":true},{"DataBaseName":"TEST","UserID":"1","WebAdmin":true},{"DataBaseName":"WA","UserID":"1","WebAdmin":true}]}

i want to print on database names in another activity in listview plz help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add android tag also. Will get quick response.

Answer (score 2):

`JSON` response is already in String format so you can just pass it to the next Activity as you are passing String to the next Activity using `intent.putExtra("JSON", response.toString());`. Then you can just get the values on the next Activity and display them.

To display data in the `ListView` just fetch the data from JSON response and add them to `ArrayList<String>` and just `bind` the ArrayList with the `Adapter` of the ListView.

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> dbName = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

  for(Integer i=0; i< valArray.length(); i++){
   
    try {
  String obj = valArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("DataBaseName");
  dbName.add(obj);
 } catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

   
  }

  
  
  
        setListAdapter(dbName);       But im getting null in ArrayAdabter so can plz help me im not getting proper result thanks in advance plz help me

Comment: yes now you can pass your dbName instance to ListView to populate it.